# Acquiring images from a live video from a TV to PC adapter

Tags: video, images, python, usb, matlab

A camera is connected to [this TV to PC adapter](http://www.avermedia.com/tv_more/product/tv/avertv_hybrid_volar_hd). It's USB output is connected to the laptop. I have to acquire images from the video continuously and process them further. I have tried using Image Acquisition toolbox of MATLAB and OpenCV in Python but I have been unable to finish the task. Some research told me that this is because my computer is recognising the overall system not as a camera but as a video controller.

Any software or language which accomplishes the task will be okay for me. Please add links to documentation if you can.

I would prefer if it's on Windows. Interfacing with either python or MATLAB would work, though I will prefer MATLAB. There is no price limit as such.

Edit: I was able to solve this by using the DVdriver software mentioned in the link I have shared in the answer. Other methods that you may suggest are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The method suggested by [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22183737/4775626) worked for me:

I used a trial version of [DVdrive](http://www.trackerpod.com/TCamWeb/download.htm) software to fool my OS into believing that the connected TV to PC adapter is a webcam and then I was able to access the device both from Python as well as MATLAB through [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) and Image Acquisition toolbox respectively.